# Floating sidebar can get too long and obscure footer

Tags: bug, asking-questions, design, sidebar

Sometimes, when you create a question which returns a lot of similar questions, it makes the height of the floating "Similiar Questions" box too big to fit on the page. As a result, it blocks some of the footer on the right hand side. *It's actually doing it as I type this question.*

I think a max height based on the `view port - footerHeight` should fix it.

[image]

Comment: For what it's worth, I've seen this numerous times and always thought it was intentional.

Comment: Maybe a "No distractions" editor like in WordPress 3.2 could be good.