# Right-hand sidebar covers the footer on the "ask question" page and markdown help page

Tags: bug, status-declined, design, footer, sidebar

I have noticed that while asking questions and scrolling to the bottom of the page, the right sidebar containing recent questions covers the footer partially. Also, a part of it goes beyond the browser's boundary. It may not be a big problem but it still doesn't look good.

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

This also happens on the [Markdown help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) page

Comment: Screenshot will give better chances to get more attention.

Comment: We need a screenshot and your exact browser version. If you have any userscripts enabled, disable them and check if the problem persists.

Comment: If you are using **IE**, make sure you are not on **Compatibility View**. Verify it once. As **Sha Dow Wiz Ard** and **Yannis Rizos** suggested provide the details.

Comment: sorry, but i am unable to show images due to <10 reputation. :(

Comment: I am using Chrome 20.0.1132.34. The only script i was running was AdBlock plus. The problem still persists after disabling it.

Comment: Similar problem with my firefox 12.0

Comment: (An upvote to post that screenshot. @Siva, why **the bold**?)

Comment: @Arjan: Sorry, I didnt get for the text "why the bold?".

Comment: @Arjan: Thanks a lot buddy! 4 more rep to go... :)

Comment: @VJ41 Should be able to do it now :)

Comment: @Nitesh:Thanks! Here it is... :)

Comment: Unable to Replicate :(

Comment: @Nitesh: Yeah... It happens in certain conditions with me too.. :/

Comment: @Nitesh: Try while editing questions.

Comment: This also happens at the [bottom of the FAQ page](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#link-what-about) ([image example](http://i.stack.imgur.com/juxoK.png)).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Floating sidebar can get too long and obscure footer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110258/floating-sidebar-can-get-too-long-and-obscure-footer)

Answer (score 24):

This should be fixed.

The current answer is:

> We think that sidebar is pretty important, and want it to remain visible. The footer, on the other hand, isn't that important, and can always be accessed again with a bit of scrolling up. It's not worth the time to tweak the page so that it's only scrollable until the point of overlap.

I personally don't think it would be hard to code, and would take into account people with smaller screens.

On top of that, when you have scrolled down far enough for it to overlap, you can't see what you are writing in the box. It is definitely pointless then, as it is referencing something off the screen.

[image]

This is a 1170x800 window, that is the smallest screen (realistically) you get without it being a mobile. While it isn't overlapping, at that point it is unhelpful and irritating.

Answer (score 8):

We think that sidebar is pretty important, and want it to remain visible. The footer, on the other hand, isn't *that* important, and can always be accessed again with a bit of scrolling up. It's not worth the time to tweak the page so that it's only scrollable until the point of overlap.

Comment: Can this be reconsidered? Especially considering http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251746/similar-questions-overlaps-footer-and-has-no-background

Comment: In Meta Stack Exchange, sidebar doesn't have a background, so its text is not legible at all: http://i.stack.imgur.com/xo7mL.jpg

Comment: @Behdad hm, good point. Ask a new [bug] question?

Comment: @Behdad It's pretty buggy even when there is a background: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNhlv.jpg