# R.H.S view is overlapping in ask questions on Meta Stack Overflow when scrolling down

Tags: bug, status-declined

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Right-hand sidebar covers the footer on the “ask question” page and markdown help page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136849/right-sidebar-comes-over-the-footer-while-asking-question)

When I was about to ask a question I saw the R.H.S view is over-lapping when scrolling down.

For more information refer to the below image:

[image]

Comment: It was on stackoverflow.com not for the meta.stackoverflow.com. It might be possible duplicate.