# "Questions that may already have your answer" box overlaps onto the footer

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, asking-questions, similar-questions

When "Questions that may already have your answer" (similar questions) appear as a right column, it overflows and overlaps the footer.  (shown in the figure)

> [image: Taken on 19/12/12]

This happens on all SE network sites on which I have asked questions.

Also this happens to other columns also like "How to Format".

Comment: Not certain that that is a bug; the cute little post-it note curl at the bottom seems to indicate it is intentional.

Comment: Ya agree u cant say it a bug, but this is most apt in the given tags.
And its cute n little . But with a improvement thet can also make the footer automatically adjustable. So I suggested

Comment: Here's a duplicate that isn't closed or deleted: [Right-hand sidebar covers the footer on the “ask question” page and markdown help page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136849/right-hand-sidebar-covers-the-footer-on-the-ask-question-page-and-markdown-hel)