# Post edit sidebar text overlaps bottom bar

Tags: bug, design, meta, footer, sidebar

I understand this has [already been addressed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110258/floating-sidebar-can-get-too-long-and-obscure-footer) but on Meta it appears the minimal style is causing this to be an issue.

[image: Overlapping edit sidebar contents]

Since it's not styled as a [post-it note](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159297/questions-that-may-already-have-your-answer-box-overlaps-onto-the-footer#comment461311_159297) or anything of the sort (i.e. no opaque background), the contents overlap and get all wonky.

This is Chrome on Mac OS X.

Comment: @ShadowWizard indeed.

Comment: Wasn't easy to find, it didn't mention that it affects only this very site. Fixed by tagging. :)