# The suggestion bar on right side of the page is overlapping on the bottom menu area (footer)

Tags: bug, design

While scrolling down the page, the suggestion bar on the right side of the page overlaps on the footer. Its difficult for me to access the options present in the footer due to overlapping.

> [image]

Pages where this issue occurs: "Ask Question" and "read the faq » "

Steps:

1. Goto "Ask Question" and scroll down.
2. You'll see suggestion bars like How to Ask, How to Format and as soon as a user types in a question, the Similar Questions bar appears.
3. Scroll down to reach the footer, observe the overlapping of the suggestion bar on the footer.

I recreated this issue on chrome and Firefox.

Comment: That's what you mean, Avian?

Comment: Yes. That's what I meant, Bart :)

Comment: Here's a duplicate that isn't closed or deleted: [Right-hand sidebar covers the footer on the “ask question” page and markdown help page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136849/right-hand-sidebar-covers-the-footer-on-the-ask-question-page-and-markdown-hel)