# Stop scrolling the sidebar at the bottom of the page

Tags: feature-request, design, site-faq

Similar to this [meta discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136849/right-sidebar-comes-over-the-footer-while-asking-question) when on the FAQ page [scrolling to the bottom of the page](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#link-what-about) causes the sidebar to cover the links at the bottom of the page. It would be nice if it stopped scrolling down, similar to how it stops at the top early.

[image]

The screenshot was taken in firefox but the same behavior is seen in IE9 (both with and without compatibility view enabled)