# Help overflow in Firefox

Tags: bug, user-interface, design

When scrolling down while editing a question ([this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18043722/41071), though that's probably not relevant), I noticed that the short help on the right side overflowed into the page footer:

[image]

I think it shouldn't do that. I'm using Firefox 22 on Windows 7.

Comment: Also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118782/why-does-similar-questions-tab-overlap-the-footer-here

Comment: Here's a duplicate that isn't closed or deleted: [Right-hand sidebar covers the footer on the “ask question” page and markdown help page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136849/right-hand-sidebar-covers-the-footer-on-the-ask-question-page-and-markdown-hel)

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be an issue with the sidebar styles that are "pinned" to stay with you even when you scroll. The problem is not unique to Firefox, or even the question page. The issue can also be observed on Election pages and in Chrome.

Any time you have one of the sidebar help boxes (or the candidate selection thingy) and not very much vertical space, it seems to be possible to scroll down far enough where the content runs into the footer.

It seems like the solution would be to limit the lower boundary of where it is allowed to follow the scroll so that it stop before cutting out of the main body area.