# "Similar questions" overlaps footer and has no background

Tags: bug, design, meta, footer, sidebar

When I can scroll down far enough to have the hot network questions overlap the footer (because my question is short) there is no background under the text:

[image: screen shot]

Could they either be given a white background: (just disable the transparency option)

[image: suggested change]

Or stop at the footer:

[image: alternate suggestion]

---

This also happens with the help text on some sites, as per this bug report:
[CSS bug on Ask Question page on Programmers and Meta site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/264158/css-bug-on-ask-question-page-on-programmers-and-meta-site)

---

Ubuntu 14.04.1 (Latest LTS Version), [Google Chrome Stable 41.0.2272.89 (Latest Version)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rASpR.png). Same problem with [Firefox 36.0.1 (Latest Version)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/STRO7.png) and [Dooble 0.07 (Latest Version, stopped development in 2009)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7eXK.png).

Windows 10 Pro, [Google Chrome Stable 41.0.2272.101 (Latest Version)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oAbnB.png) and [Internet Explorer Spartan 11.0.9800.00 (Latest Version)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0f5W2.png).

(Images linked to screenshot of browser)

My question is different from [Right-hand sidebar covers the footer on the "ask question" page and markdown help page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136849/right-hand-sidebar-covers-the-footer-on-the-ask-question-page-and-markdown-hel) because my issue is the lack of background on the footer.

[It did have this not long ago.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136849/right-hand-sidebar-covers-the-footer-on-the-ask-question-page-and-markdown-hel) I think there was a site redesign?

Comment: The first option looks crappy. I agree with the second one in my opinion.

Comment: @Arceus https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136849/right-hand-sidebar-covers-the-footer-on-the-ask-question-page-and-markdown-hel

Comment: @Tim ahh. Thanks. Sorry :P

Comment: It is meant to be like that :p Site was redesigned I think...

Comment: retagged since it's also affecting more pages.

Comment: also relevant in http://tex.stackexchange.com/ where the sidebar has `rgba(253,245,213,0.5)` as background color

Comment: Looks like this has been fixed on meta.SE at least; the sidebar now has a white background and a gray border. If a similar issue still occurs on other sites, a specific report should probably be posted on those sites' metas.