# Is there a way to find known issues?

Tags: support, bug-reports

Is there a way to go through list of known issues? That way it would be easy to not raise duplicate defects by the community. Sometimes the search string might not match with what ever a user is looking for. Just a thought.

Also I tried to search for Known-Issues as attached from the screen shot but nothing pop'ed up.[image]

Example : I was trying to post a defect where the Similar Questions section is overlapping on the footer section. I will have to go through the ask question instead of finding it out directly.

Comment: Duplicates aren't amazing, but they're not evil. If you can't find it by searching for your suggested title and a few keywords, just post.

Comment: You could try searching with the key words of your question (eg. [similar questions overlap](http://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=similar+questions+overlap) --> [“Similar questions” overlaps footer and has no background](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251746/similar-questions-overlaps-footer-and-has-no-background). But, Stack Exchange's search is pretty bad - just google it with `site:[site.com]` :)

Comment: Agree. Stack exchange search is bad.

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ and Giene - not bad, just need one to get used to it. After years of lurking here, searching became a second nature for me. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard if you say so... but you've got to admit sometimes it's easier to just google it :P

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ nope, too much noise in the form of unrelated comments, wrong tags, etc.

Comment: Any reason you keep accepting and unaccepting my answer?

Comment: Ya kind of thinking why someone has to be so stereotype when this application is suppose to be a community helping people instead of doing the opposite.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just look in this very site front page. If you don't see what you want to report listed there, go ahead and report it.

Long time members might think "hey, this rings a bell!", dig and search and finally close as duplicate.

No harm done, and this will help searching for the same issue in the future by adding more existing key words attached to it.

Over time, if you'll stick around you'll learn how to use Meta and search for existing reports/requests, which is basically done in the way described by Anna [in this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/257043/).

Answer (score 9):

For one, you're searching for "kown" issues, not "known" issues.

But aside from that... you may consider anything tagged [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) and without any [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)/[status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)/[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) tags as known/reported. Not every bug will be fixed, but tagging as [bug] + whatever other tags may be relevant is sufficient for reporting an issue.

Comment: those pesky 'kown' issues, they get everywhere!