# CSS bug on Ask Question page on Programmers and Meta site

Tags: bug, design, asking-questions

I just came across a CSS issue. When I scroll down on the Ask Question page on Programmers, Meta Programmers, Workplace, Meta Workplace, and Meta Stack Exchange site, I see text overlapping the footer,.

*The help text goes **behind** the footer, linked question says help text comes **over** footer.*

**Improper css :**
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/ask

[image: Programmers Ask Question]

**Improper css**

https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask

[image: Meta Programmers Ask Question]

**Improper css :**

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask

[image: Meta Stack Exchange Ask Question]

**Proper CSS :**
[Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)

[image: Stack Overflow Ask Question]

This can be reproduced in Firefox and Chrome.

*This is not duplicate of [Right-hand sidebar covers the footer on the "ask question" page and markdown help page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136849/right-hand-sidebar-covers-the-footer-on-the-ask-question-page-and-markdown-hel) as my question says the help text goes **behind** the footer not over it.*

Comment: This is Not duplicate as My Question says the Help text goes Behind Footer

Comment: @inɒzɘmɒЯ.A.M No, it's not. Reading that, it looks like it's intentional that the sidebar covers the footer so that the sidebar is always readable (see the very last picture). However, look at the pictures from Programmers - the sidebar and footer intermingle so that neither is really readable.

Comment: @Thomas right; sorry, too bad I can't retract flags.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yeah you are right. One is by design as otherwise it would push the footer down. The text going behind is a bug. I've retracted my close vote, and made more coffee..

Comment: Bug told in that question is not solved till now ! **:(**

Comment: @PratikCJoshi: yup, probably because the design team is miles behind on the backlog.

Comment: If you give me a chance , I may correct that CSS issue in 5 minutes ! **:(**  . Atleast I reminded this issue exists on Programmers too and the duplicate question(http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251746/similar-questions-overlaps-footer-and-has-no-background) says bug is still **Opened**.

Comment: @PratikCJoshi The Stack Exchange dev and web design team are capable of fixing basic CSS issues - just look around at the sites and apps they have ;) 5 mins is not a fair statement if you consider their test and roll out procedures, and importantly other work priorities :) I've edited the other question to note this one, which will bump it to the front page, but feel free to add a bounty if the problem urks you enough to have it noticed more :)

Comment: bounty ? How much reputation i have here on meta S.E.? ? :) Lol

Comment: even 50 would be enough to get it noticed, and you'd still have enough to do most important things here like comment and vote up - and vote down now I've upvoted you here +5 ;) (you could also add an answer stating this happens with the help text, show an image, and sites where you have reproduced, and you'll probs get an upvote or two, so loss would be 20 or 30 rep, tho I wouldn't be surprised if you ended up breaking even or positive)