# SE Ask Question page bug - affects multiple sites

Tags: support, bug, design

The Ask Questions page seems to have some issues with the menu on the right.  I noticed it in Workplace and it also seems to affect Meta-SE.

This is not a duplicate of "[Right-hand sidebar covers the footer on the "ask question" page and markdown help page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136849/right-hand-sidebar-covers-the-footer-on-the-ask-question-page-and-markdown-hel)"  because it is the **opposite** of what that question is reporting.  e.g.) The menu is NOT covering the footer properly.

To replicate, I simply scroll to the bottom.

I am on Windows 8 running Chrome Version 46.0.2490.71 m

The ask page on SO seems fine.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: @vaultah It's not a duplicate.  I'm reporting the problem that the side bar is meshing text with the footer.  The link shows the footer is *being covered* by the side bar, which is exactly what is *not* happen here :)

Comment: [“Similar questions” overlaps footer and has no background](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251746/similar-questions-overlaps-footer-and-has-no-background)

Comment: Hmm, there's a chain of related questions and seems to be... "Working As Intended"?  Weird...

Comment: Pops sums it up nicely in his answer: "We think that sidebar is pretty important, and want it to remain visible. The footer, on the other hand, isn't that important, and can always be accessed again with a bit of scrolling up"

Comment: Worth to mention, that here on MSE this is indeed a bug due to missing background, and already [reported here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251746/similar-questions-overlaps-footer-and-has-no-background).