# Floating sidebar clash with footer in team page

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, company-page

Here is a screenshot from [Stackoverflow Team](https://stackoverflow.com/company/team) page, with the floating sidebar: (all good so far)

> [image: Stackoverflow Team]

After I scroll down to footer it just combines both:

> [image]

Can it please be fixed?

Comment: I don't see a problem, unless I am unwilling to replicate. Can you explain what you mean but "it just combine both"?

Comment: Looking at the bottom, the white portion of the page has merged into the black footer of the page. I'ts more noticable if you look just to the left of the black part and at the words

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing. Basically, the sidebar with the job categories stays static and still stays on the screen even when the only visible part is the footer

Comment: just scroll down to end. Side bar "community", "customer Support" combined(Merged) with the website footer (Technology).

Comment: I think they may be referring to how the left hand panel text can be seen through or along with the headings in the black bottom panel.  If they did a screenshot of just that part of the browser window it would be obvious.

Comment: @Ordis you explain it good. Just what I want to say

Comment: Doesn't happen for me. I'm running at 2560x1440 though.

Comment: Yeah, the left-side nav bleeds into the footer when you scroll all the way down. Reproduced in Chrome (latest).

Comment: [This was already reported on SO meta a few days ago](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318357/left-menu-on-teams-page-overlaps-the-footer)

Comment: @Carpetsmoker well, since Stack Overflow is now Stack Exchange (the company) this fits both meta sites

Comment: While it's not the same page, this is scarily similar to [the design bug that was 'status-declined'](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136849/). I guess the only solution is to [give background color](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251746/)

Comment: @AndrewT. Not agree with your comment

Comment: @SID He wasn't really giving an opinion of what he thinks should happen, but state what is likely to happen. It's very likely, based on past reports, that this bug will get "fixed" by simply adding a white background on that menu so the items don't blend into the footer behind it, and it overlapping on the footer will be by-design, as we've been unwilling to implement a change to make sidebar items stop at the footer in the past.

Comment: @animuson if you give white background Technology in black panel will be like below to the side panel

Comment: @SID Which is something we don't mind. This happens on *one* page on our site, and if you really want to see that column in the footer, you can easily go to *any other page* on the site and look at it.

Comment: @animuson I know that Sir, I thought its bug that's why I reported bug. the same footer also available under this question too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This bug has been fixed recently.