# Sidebar overlaps footer on markdown help page

Tags: bug, design, footer, sidebar, editing-help

After I scroll down to the bottom of the [`editing-help`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help) page I see sidebar overlapping footer. Almost like in this question: [Floating sidebar clash with footer in team page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/276604/floating-sidebar-clash-with-footer-in-team-page)

Screenshot:

[image: <code>editing-help</code> page screenshot]

Comment: I actually found other similar question but they seem to be closed or inactive and bug remains unfixed

Comment: I picked that dupe because this also is a z-index issue.