# Editing notes overflow into footer without background

Tags: bug, status-declined

As I was about to edit a question on Stackoverflow (and Meta) I noticed the sidebar notes overflow into the footer. This also seems to be happening in meta.

Happens to me on:

- Chrome 41 OS X
- Firefox 37 OS X
- Safari 8

[image]

[image: Notes overflow issue]

**Update**

Since there is a [similar question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136849/right-hand-sidebar-covers-the-footer-on-the-ask-question-page-and-markdown-hel), let me update my question and target specifically Meta. Since the question already has an answer and it states the sidebar is more important, then maybe on sites like Meta.SE where the sidebar is transparent, there should be a white background.

Comment: @Mat edited my question to no longer be a duplicate and point out a separate but still related issue

Comment: @Mat wrong dupe. I found the correct one. :)