# Technical UI bug on the Moderator Election page

Tags: bug, design, election

Today I checked the Moderator Election Phase page and found a technical glitch. It's the side div stating the choice selection of moderator candidates. Upon scrolling the candidate descriptive answers changes but the choice made stayed there which is the desired behavior.

But at the bottom of the page the div crosses the main div and therefore overlapping the social media links. The data shown in the screenshot should be kept confidential but without the screenshot it would be hard to understand so I have entered the choices according to the reputation of the candidates and this is not my final vote. [image]

Browser: Mozilla Firefox.

Comment: There are more issues with  floating boxes in right-hand pane: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136849/right-hand-sidebar-covers-the-footer-on-the-ask-question-page-and-markdown-hel

Comment: It works fine as expected on the mobile desktop version

Comment: Just checked again if any relevant developer at stack-exchange has solved the issue or not but it seems this has not gathered special attention so finally I am placing a bounty. Hope someone sees it and try to fix it.

Comment: none of the other floating box issues have been solved so I wouldn't have high hopes for a page that is even seen by less users then all the others ...

Comment: The election is going to be closed within 9 hours and there's nothing they have fixed or responded to my question even after I placed bounty. Looks like they are making the quote "We don't run this site; the community does!" true. And since the community is not responsible for the source code of the site itself the question lays untouched. Although I have seen many community managers and developers at stack-exchange who have diamond attached to their name and are involving themselves in various Q&A but looks like they are not interested to make sure the site works flawless@rene

Comment: @parthu_panther The bounty also isn't getting responded, disappointing...