# Info-box on 'Edit Tag-wiki' page overflows when page is scrolled to the bottom

Tags: bug, tags, design, suggested-edits, tag-wiki

I was recently editing a Tag-wiki when I realised that when I scrolled the page to the bottom, the info-box on the right overflowed and blocked out certain options such as 'Facebook', 'Twitter' and others.

[image]

Is this [status-bydesign] or a [bug]?

Comment: I think so, see [Right-hand sidebar covers the footer on the “ask question” page and markdown help page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/136849/295232)

Comment: @Glorfindel, just viewed it. It seems more or less the same, but I think it should be fixed. It IS rather annoying :)