# Why are "related questions" suddenly appearing above the answer input (instead of in the right sidebar) for unanswered questions?

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, design, related-questions

(outdated context): I was seeing this on *all* network sites.

Screenshot from MSO:
[image]

Did something with [A/B testing related questions within the answers list (testing has concluded)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/423143/11107541) go out of control?

> We are initially focusing our efforts on questions without answers in order to validate whether the inline placement results in better engagement before we iterate on question pages with at least one answer.

Comment: Related (MSO): [A/B testing related questions within the answers list (testing has concluded)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/423143/a-b-testing-related-questions-within-the-answers-list-testing-has-concluded)

Comment: Surely [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136849/right-hand-sidebar-covers-the-footer-on-the-ask-question-page-and-markdown-hel) from the related questions list would be helpful in solving this inquiry

Comment: Theory: this is to increase the answer rate by making the design of unanswered question so annoying that people will post answer out of desperation just to get rid of it :)

Comment: @KevinB or maybe the second one in the list: [Why are the moderators being so strict with quality related flags recently?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160754)

Comment: @KevinB ah yes. or [this](/q/11740), [this](/q/19190), or [this](/q/99502)

Comment: Are these the "Have you seen these?" questions which are presented during the asking process?

Comment: @AndrewLeach no it's the "Related" questions from the sidebar.

Comment: @ShadowTheSpringWizard Ah. I thought it might actually be useful.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Update**: A fix has been deployed. The module will only appear on Stack Overflow question pages with no answers.

Thanks for letting us know. The new module was originally part of an [experiment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/423143/11107541) which concluded. We graduated the experiment today but it was supposed to only be available on the Stack Overflow site instead of across the network. The experiment post will be updated to announce the graduation.

We'll be deploying a change to make this only available on Stack Overflow. We apologize for the inconvenience caused. It was not our intention to make this change across the network sites.

Comment: "_The experiment post will be updated to announce the graduation._" out of curiosity, why not a new question post to announce it as well? And why graduate it before announcing it instead of while / after announcing it?

Comment: I think you'll have to dig long and hard to find a feature more noisy than this one. Please undo the change

Comment: @starball there will be a new post from the Community Management team soon that explains the upcoming changes regarding communications for the Content Discovery initiative. More information will be shared soon.

Comment: Nothing personal, but I just get overall feeling such "mistakes" happens more and more. Sometimes taking long weeks until the mistake is fixed. And sorry, I don't like it. Thanks for taking a look and considering removing it from SE sites though.

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine I think [thank you reaction](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/398367/839601) was worse than that (not by a large margin though)