# Formatting error while editing question

Tags: bug, design, meta

I have posted one question on this website. While editing it, after scrolling down, I found this:

[image: A screenshot].

Kindly change it.

Comment: [Another question describing same problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/110258)

Comment: Its in StackOverflow also - http://i.stack.imgur.com/2dS1N.png