# When asking questions, guidelines sidebar overlaps with footer when scrolled down

Tags: bug, design

Related:

[Right-hand sidebar covers the footer on the “ask question” page and markdown help page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/136849/310741)

[Floating sidebar can get too long and obscure footer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/110258/310741)

When asking questions on Meta Stack Exchange, sidebar overlaps with footer and since its background is transparent, its text is not legible. In most SE sites, like Stack Overflow, it has an opaque background so there's no problem, but on Meta Stack Exchange itself, it doesn't have a background. See these two pictures:

**Asking a question on Stack Overflow:**

[image]

**Asking a question on Meta Stack Exchange:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for following up!

Comment: @Pops if this is a follow up of https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136849/right-hand-sidebar-covers-the-footer-on-the-ask-question-page-and-markdown-hel#comment876317_236369, should it be reopened?

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ It is closed as a duplicate of a completely different report which identifies this exact issue. They just weren't aware it was alreasy reported.

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ Right, and the duplicate I used is about the illegibility of that text, because it lacks a background. So what's the problem?

Comment: D'oh, you're right, I just wasn't aware this had already been reported. The current closure state of this question seems correct to me.

Comment: @animuson hmm, I seemed to have got mixed up with my tabs :/ I had the status-declined one open! Sorry!

Comment: @Pops good morning! This design bug exists ever since MSE/MSO split, i.e. part of the initial MSE design. :)